# Ruby and MongoDB: require 'uri' returns false, should return true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I'm trying to connect to my remote mongoDB database through irb shell.

I ran the following:

```
2.3.0 :001 > require 'mongo'
 => true 
2.3.0 :002 > Mongo::Logger.logger.level = ::Logger::INFO
 => 1 
2.3.0 :003 > require 'uri'
 => false
```

The last statement should return true. I attempted to initialise the client after this via:

```
db = Mongo::Client.new(ENV['MLAB_URI'])
```

And got the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: `require` returning `false` means that the file has already been required, maybe by the library.

Comment: Oh okay.. So what could be going wrong when I try to initialise the db?

Comment: `Mongo::Client#initialize` expects an **array** of strings, but you passed a `nil` to it. Obviously the environment variable `MLAB_URI` is not set correctly.

Comment: When i entered it I did put the actual URI, and I double checked that the username and password were correct..

Comment: db = Mongo::Client.new(ENV['mongodb://<username>:<password>@ds041526.mlab.com:41526/coursera_zips'])

Comment: <username> and <password> have actual username and password in their place.

Comment: Try hard code the uri first. `db = Mongo::Client.new('mongodb://<username>:<password>@ds041‌​526.mlab.com:41526/c‌​oursera_zips')`

Comment: That worked!!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you haven't set the ENV variable .
check ENV['MLAB_URI'] variable value.

Comment: In the terminal I entered "set MLAB_URI=mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds041526.mlab.com:41526/coursera_zips" with my actual username and password, which I double checked. Since that didn't work in irb I went ahead and pasted in the URI rather than MLAB_URI but I still get the same problem.